# Narrator not reading the textblock's text consistently in windows phone 8.1 WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, accessibility, windows-10-mobile

I am working in a windows phone 8.1 winrt application in which i was asked to design controls to be screen readable. If narrator is enabled in windows phone, controls has to read their content when user access the controls in phone. After narrator is enabled, textblock is not reading the text consistently. It hardly reads the text for one or two times. But button, textbox & slider controls are reading their content smoothly.

To turn on narrator in windows phone (settings > ease of access > Narrator )

I had created a sample in windows phone 8.1 silverlight, in there textblock reads the text smoothly for all the time.

But in windows 10 mobile also the textblock is not reading the text

My Sample Xaml code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="display" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" textblock default reader" FontSize="30" AutomationProperties.Name="textblock automation reader"/>
<TextBox AutomationProperties.Name="Textbox automation reader"/>
<Slider Value="100" Name="slider" AutomationProperties.Name="Slider atomation reader"/>
<Button Content="button default reader" AutomationProperties.Name="button automation reader"/>
```

Note: In textblock & button, narrator reads the AutomationProperties.Name property. If the AutomationProperties.Name property is removed, it reads the 
Text and Content property respectively.

**TextBox, Slider & Button:**
For textbox, slider & button the narrator is reading the AutomationProperties.Name property in both silverlight(windows phone 8.1) & in winrt (windows phone 8.1 & windows 10 mobile)

**TextBlock:**
But in winrt (windows phone 8.1 & windows 10 mobile) narrator is not reading the AutomationProperties.Name property at anytime, for text property it hardly reads for one or two time.

I refereed net for this issue, i had found one article which solves the textblock problem (in winrt) in our project by customizing the control.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jsocha/2012/11/20/making-a-textblock-in-a-datatemplate-accessible/

It is actually for accessing the textblock inside the data template. Anyway it solves the textblock accessibility problem. But for our project we are trying to solve it without customizing the control.

Is there any other way to make the textblock accessible?

Any help will be appreciated..